# AS3 : #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, air

I would like to ask for your help with my code. It compiles ok but upon reaching the below code it throws this error :

> Error  #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object
>   reference at
>   HiddenObjects_fla::MainTimeline/myFunction()[HiddenObjects_fla.MainTimeline::frame12:9]

I do not have a frame 12 in my main timeline.

```
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.*;

addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,myFunction);
function myFunction(event:Event):void {
var lazania:int = 0;
typewriter_piece1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, start_drag_piece1);
typewriter_piece1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stop_drag_piece1);
typewriter_piece2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, start_drag_piece2); 
typewriter_piece2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stop_drag_piece2);
typewriter_piece3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, start_drag_piece3);
typewriter_piece3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stop_drag_piece3);
typewriter_piece4.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, start_drag_piece4);
typewriter_piece4.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stop_drag_piece4);
typewriter_piece5.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, start_drag_piece5);
typewriter_piece5.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stop_drag_piece5);
typewriter_piece6.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, start_drag_piece6);
typewriter_piece6.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stop_drag_piece6);
stop();

//typewriter piece 1 = K 
function start_drag_piece1(event:MouseEvent):void{
typewriter_piece1.startDrag();
};
function stop_drag_piece1(event:MouseEvent):void{
if (Target1.hitTestObject(typewriter_piece1.Target1_Button)){
    typewriter_piece1.stopDrag();
    typewriter_piece1.x = Target1.x;
    typewriter_piece1.y = Target1.y;
    typewriter_piece1.mouseEnabled = false;
    typewriter_piece1.mouseChildren = false;
    lazania++;
    if(lazania == 6){
        typewriter_piece1.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, start_drag_piece1);
        typewriter_piece1.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stop_drag_piece1);
        typewriter_piece2.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, start_drag_piece2);
        typewriter_piece2.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stop_drag_piece2);
        typewriter_piece3.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, start_drag_piece3);
        typewriter_piece3.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stop_drag_piece3);
        typewriter_piece4.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, start_drag_piece4);
        typewriter_piece4.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stop_drag_piece4);
        typewriter_piece5.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, start_drag_piece5);
        typewriter_piece5.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stop_drag_piece5);
        typewriter_piece6.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, start_drag_piece6);
        typewriter_piece6.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stop_drag_piece6);
        gotoAndStop(1, "Scene 5");
    }
    //checklazania(lazania);
}
else{
    typewriter_piece1.x = 25;
    typewriter_piece1.y = 139,95;
    typewriter_piece1.stopDrag();
}
};

//typewriter piece 2 = Y 
function start_drag_piece2(event:MouseEvent):void{
typewriter_piece2.startDrag();
};
function stop_drag_piece2(event:MouseEvent):void{
if (Target2.hitTestObject(typewriter_piece2.Target2_Button)){
    typewriter_piece2.stopDrag();
    typewriter_piece2.x = Target2.x;
    typewriter_piece2.y = Target2.y;
    typewriter_piece2.mouseEnabled = false;
    typewriter_piece2.mouseChildren = false;
    lazania++;
    if(lazania == 6){
        typewriter_piece1.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, start_drag_piece1);
        typewriter_piece1.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stop_drag_piece1);
        typewriter_piece2.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, start_drag_piece2);
        typewriter_piece2.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stop_drag_piece2);
        typewriter_piece3.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, start_drag_piece3);
        typewriter_piece3.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stop_drag_piece3);
        typewriter_piece4.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, start_drag_piece4);
        typewriter_piece4.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stop_drag_piece4);
        typewriter_piece5.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, start_drag_piece5);
        typewriter_piece5.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stop_drag_piece5);
        typewriter_piece6.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, start_drag_piece6);
        typewriter_piece6.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stop_drag_piece6);
        gotoAndStop(1, "Scene 5");
    }
    //checklazania(lazania);

}
else{
    typewriter_piece2.x = 25;
    typewriter_piece2.y = 179,95;       
    typewriter_piece2.stopDrag();
}
};

//typewriter piece 3 = Π
function start_drag_piece3(event:MouseEvent):void{
typewriter_piece3.startDrag()
};
function stop_drag_piece3(event:MouseEvent):void{
if (Target3.hitTestObject(typewriter_piece3.Target3_Button)){
    typewriter_piece3.stopDrag();
    typewriter_piece3.x = Target3.x;
    typewriter_piece3.y = Target3.y;
    typewriter_piece3.mouseEnabled = false;
    typewriter_piece3.mouseChildren = false;
    lazania++;
    if(lazania == 6){
        typewriter_piece1.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, start_drag_piece1);
        typewriter_piece1.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stop_drag_piece1);
        typewriter_piece2.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, start_drag_piece2);
        typewriter_piece2.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stop_drag_piece2);
        typewriter_piece3.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, start_drag_piece3);
        typewriter_piece3.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stop_drag_piece3);
        typewriter_piece4.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, start_drag_piece4);
        typewriter_piece4.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stop_drag_piece4);
        typewriter_piece5.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, start_drag_piece5);
        typewriter_piece5.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stop_drag_piece5);
        typewriter_piece6.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, start_drag_piece6);
        typewriter_piece6.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stop_drag_piece6);
        gotoAndStop(1, "Scene 5");
    }
    //checklazania(lazania);
}
else{
    typewriter_piece3.x = 25;
    typewriter_piece3.y = 219,95;       
    typewriter_piece3.stopDrag();
}
};

//typewriter piece 4 = P
function start_drag_piece4(event:MouseEvent):void{
typewriter_piece4.startDrag()
};
function stop_drag_piece4(event:MouseEvent):void{
if (Target4.hitTestObject(typewriter_piece4.Target4_Button)){
    typewriter_piece4.stopDrag();
    typewriter_piece4.x = Target4.x;
    typewriter_piece4.y = Target4.y;
    typewriter_piece4.mouseEnabled = false;
    typewriter_piece4.mouseChildren = false;
    lazania++;
    if(lazania == 6){
        typewriter_piece1.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, start_drag_piece1);
        typewriter_piece1.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stop_drag_piece1);
        typewriter_piece2.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, start_drag_piece2);
        typewriter_piece2.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stop_drag_piece2);
        typewriter_piece3.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, start_drag_piece3);
        typewriter_piece3.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stop_drag_piece3);
        typewriter_piece4.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, start_drag_piece4);
        typewriter_piece4.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stop_drag_piece4);
        typewriter_piece5.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, start_drag_piece5);
        typewriter_piece5.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stop_drag_piece5);
        typewriter_piece6.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, start_drag_piece6);
        typewriter_piece6.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stop_drag_piece6);
        gotoAndStop(1, "Scene 5");
    }   
    //checklazania(lazania);
}
else{
    typewriter_piece4.x = 25;
    typewriter_piece4.y = 259,95;
    typewriter_piece4.stopDrag();
}
};

//typewriter piece 5 = O
function start_drag_piece5(event:MouseEvent):void{
typewriter_piece5.startDrag()
};
function stop_drag_piece5(event:MouseEvent):void{
if (Target5.hitTestObject(typewriter_piece5.Target5_Button)){
    typewriter_piece5.stopDrag();
    typewriter_piece5.x = Target5.x;
    typewriter_piece5.y = Target5.y;
    typewriter_piece5.mouseEnabled = false;
    typewriter_piece5.mouseChildren = false;
    lazania++;
    if(lazania == 6){
        typewriter_piece1.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, start_drag_piece1);
        typewriter_piece1.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stop_drag_piece1);
        typewriter_piece2.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, start_drag_piece2);
        typewriter_piece2.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stop_drag_piece2);
        typewriter_piece3.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, start_drag_piece3);
        typewriter_piece3.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stop_drag_piece3);
        typewriter_piece4.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, start_drag_piece4);
        typewriter_piece4.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stop_drag_piece4);
        typewriter_piece5.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, start_drag_piece5);
        typewriter_piece5.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stop_drag_piece5);
        typewriter_piece6.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, start_drag_piece6);
        typewriter_piece6.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stop_drag_piece6);
        gotoAndStop(1, "Scene 5");
    }
    //checklazania(lazania);
}
else{
    typewriter_piece5.x = 25;
    typewriter_piece5.y = 299,95;

    typewriter_piece5.stopDrag();
}
};

//typewriter piece 6 = Σ
function start_drag_piece6(event:MouseEvent):void{
typewriter_piece6.startDrag()
};
function stop_drag_piece6(event:MouseEvent):void{
if (Target6.hitTestObject(typewriter_piece6.Target6_Button)){
    typewriter_piece6.stopDrag();
    typewriter_piece6.x = Target6.x;
    typewriter_piece6.y = Target6.y;
    typewriter_piece6.mouseEnabled = false;
    typewriter_piece6.mouseChildren = false;
    lazania++;
    if(lazania == 6){
        typewriter_piece1.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, start_drag_piece1);
        typewriter_piece1.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stop_drag_piece1);
        typewriter_piece2.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, start_drag_piece2);
        typewriter_piece2.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stop_drag_piece2);
        typewriter_piece3.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, start_drag_piece3);
        typewriter_piece3.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stop_drag_piece3);
        typewriter_piece4.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, start_drag_piece4);
        typewriter_piece4.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stop_drag_piece4);
        typewriter_piece5.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, start_drag_piece5);
        typewriter_piece5.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stop_drag_piece5);
        typewriter_piece6.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, start_drag_piece6);
        typewriter_piece6.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stop_drag_piece6);
        gotoAndStop(1, "Scene 5");
    }
    //checklazania(lazania);
}
else{
    typewriter_piece6.x = 25;
    typewriter_piece6.y = 339,95;
    typewriter_piece6.stopDrag();
}
};

}
```

Comment: Thats some mad coding, you should really looking into patterns, looping that kind of thing, it can save you a lot. even though most of that is just cutting and pasting your previous functions, its easy to get lost among it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're problem is likely this:

```
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,myFunction);
```

Even when you call `stop()`, your `myFunction` will continue to run once every frame as per you're applications frame rate.   So if you're frame rate is set to 24, myFunction is running 24 times every second.  That means you're adding all those listeners again and again 24 times every second. (assuming your `myFunction` ends after those mouse event listeners, you're missing the closing `}` so I have to guess).

You're also never removing that `ENTER_FRAME` listener, so even after you've moved on to another part of your program (via your `gotoAndStop` lines), that `myFunction` will continue to be called 24 times every second.   The 1009 error is likely because you've moved on to another frame where your `typewriter_piece` instances no longer exist, but the ENTER_FRAME handler is still running that function over and over.

Take the following code:

```
typewriter_piece1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, start_drag_piece1);
typewriter_piece1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stop_drag_piece1);
typewriter_piece2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, start_drag_piece2); 
typewriter_piece2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stop_drag_piece2);
typewriter_piece3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, start_drag_piece3);
typewriter_piece3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stop_drag_piece3);
typewriter_piece4.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, start_drag_piece4);
typewriter_piece4.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stop_drag_piece4);
typewriter_piece5.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, start_drag_piece5);
typewriter_piece5.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stop_drag_piece5);
typewriter_piece6.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, start_drag_piece6);
typewriter_piece6.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stop_drag_piece6);
stop();
```

Out of myFunction (so it just runs on the frame),  and remove the ENTER_FRAME listener line of code.

---

As a tip for efficiency and sanity,  try doing the following:

```
//This will add all your listeners with just 3 lines of code
for(var i:int=1;i<7;i++){
    this["typewriter_piece"+i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, startDrag);
}

//you can use the same drag handler function, and get the item with event.currentTarget
function startDrag(event:MouseEvent):void {
    var typewriter:MovieClip = event.currentTarget as MovieClip; //gets the one that was clicked/mouse downed

    var target:MovieClip = getTarget(typewriter); //get the appropriate target

    if(target.hitTestObject(typewriter)){
        typewriter.stopDrag();
        //do the rest
    }
}

//get the appropriate target
function getTarget(typeWriter:MovieClip):MovieClip {
    for(var i:int=1;i<7;i++){
        if(typeWriter == this["typewriter_piece"+i]){
            return this["Target"+i];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the myfunction function. As long as it is a function it is live for the whole of the program. If you take it out it is only live for the specific frame. That way the program will not ask, check or bother with this code as soon as you move out. It becomes live as soon as you enter the frame because of the enter frame command at the top of your code. Let everything else as it is... It is nice to see that the solution worked!!! :p

Comment: Thanks, it solved the null reference problem. now i encountered a different type of bug. the first time I try to run the above mentioned part of the program it automatically tosses me 3 frames back in another scene that is not even mentioned in the code. if i continue normally from there i encounter no problems.